# Aligning x position of tspan in IE11 using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

Really struggling with this. I've tried a lot of hacks to get the labels to render correctly on my force directed d3 graph. Here is a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-4cuunq?file=src/app/directed-graph-experiment.service.ts)

You will notice in all other browsers except IE11 renders ok.

[image]

In IE:

[image]

As you can see in IE11 the first `<tspan>` isn't anchored to the middle. I've tried a combination of things with and without the `x` attribute, `dx` manipulation. I have lined them up via the `dx` attribute but as each set of labels have different lengths the math isn't the same for each.

The svg structure is as follows:

```
<text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel0" font-size="10" style="text-anchor: middle;">
   <textPath xlink:href="#edgepath0" dominant-baseline="middle" startOffset="50%" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <tspan class="edgelabels" dx="0">label one</tspan>
      <tspan class="edgelabels" x="0" dy="22" dx="0">label two</tspan>
      <tspan class="edgelabels" x="0" dy="22" dx="0">label three</tspan>
   </textPath>
</text>
```

You can see above in this particular implementation I intentionally left out the `x` attribute for the first tspan.

This is the code that renders the above:

```
const edgelabels = zoomContainer
  .selectAll('.edgelabel')
  .data(links)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('class', 'edgelabel')
  .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('id', function (d, i) {
    return 'edgelabel' + i;
  })
  .attr('font-size', 10);

edgelabels
  .append('textPath')
  .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {
    return '#edgepath' + i;
  })
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('dominant-baseline', 'middle')
  .attr('startOffset', '50%')
  .selectAll('div.textPath')
  .data(function (d, i) {
    return d.label;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('tspan')
  .attr('class', 'edgelabels')
  .text(function (d, i) {
    return console.log(d), d;
  })
  .attr('x', function (d, i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  })
  .attr('dy', function (d, i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      return 22;
    }
  })
  .attr('dx', 0);
```

Has anybody else had this issue, can you see anything wrong? Is there anything else I could try to get a consistent dx attribute for each set of labels? Could I restructure the code to get a better result?

Complete file code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DirectedGraphExperimentService {
  constructor() {}

  /** A method to bind a zoom behaviour to the svg g element */
  public applyZoomableBehaviour(svgElement, containerElement) {
    let svg, container, zoomed, zoom;

    svg = d3.select(svgElement);

    container = d3.select(containerElement);

    zoomed = () => {
      const transform = d3.event.transform;
      container.attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' +
          transform.x +
          ',' +
          transform.y +
          ') scale(' +
          transform.k +
          ')'
      );
    };

    zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5, 1]).on('zoom', zoomed);

    svg.call(zoom).style('cursor', 'move');
  }

  private clearView(svg) {
    return svg.selectAll('*').remove();
  }

  private ticked(link, node, edgepaths, edgelabels) {
    link
      .attr('x1', function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr('y1', function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr('x2', function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr('y2', function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node.attr('transform', function (d) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ', ' + d.y + ')';
    });

    edgepaths.attr('d', function (d) {
      return (
        'M ' +
        d.source.x +
        ' ' +
        d.source.y +
        ' L ' +
        d.target.x +
        ' ' +
        d.target.y
      );
    });

    edgelabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
      if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
        let bbox = this.getBBox();

        let rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
        let ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
        return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
      } else {
        return 'rotate(0)';
      }
    });
  }

  private dragended(d3, d, simulation) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  private initDefinitions(svg) {
    svg
      .append('defs')
      .append('marker')
      .attr('id', 'arrowhead')
      .attr('viewBox', '-0 -5 10 10')
      .attr('refX', 27)
      .attr('refY', 0)
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .attr('markerWidth', 8)
      .attr('markerHeight', 8)
      .attr('xoverflow', 'visible')
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
      .attr('fill', '#999')
      .style('stroke', 'none');
    return svg;
  }

  private forceSimulation(d3, { width, height }) {
    return d3
      .forceSimulation()
      .force(
        'link',
        d3
          .forceLink()
          .id(function (d) {
            return d.id;
          })
          .distance(500)
          .strength(2)
      )
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
  }

  private _update(d3, svg, data) {
    let { links, nodes } = data;

    // this.clearView(svg); // removes everything!
    this.initDefinitions(svg);
    const simulation = this.forceSimulation(d3, {
      width: +svg.attr('width'),
      height: +svg.attr('height'),
    });

    const zoomContainer = d3.select('svg g');

    const link = zoomContainer
      .selectAll('.link')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .style('stroke', '#999')
      .style('stroke-opacity', '.6')
      .style('stroke-width', '2px')
      .attr('class', 'link')
      .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)');

    link.append('title').text(function (d) {
      return d.label;
    });

    const edgepaths = zoomContainer
      .selectAll('.edgepath')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', 'edgepath')
      .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0)
      .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return 'edgepath' + i;
      });

    const edgelabels = zoomContainer
      .selectAll('.edgelabel')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'edgelabel')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return 'edgelabel' + i;
      })
      .attr('font-size', 10);

    edgelabels
      .append('textPath')
      .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {
        return '#edgepath' + i;
      })
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .attr('dominant-baseline', 'middle')
      .attr('startOffset', '50%')

      .selectAll('div.textPath')
      .data(function (d, i) {
        return d.label;
      })
      .enter()
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('class', 'edgelabels')
      .text(function (d, i) {
        return console.log(d), d;
      })
      .attr('x', function (d, i) {
        if (i > 0) {
          return 0;
        }
      })
      .attr('dy', function (d, i) {
        if (i > 0) {
          return 22;
        }
      })
      .attr('dx', 0);
    svg.selectAll('.edgelabel').on('click', function () {
      // arrow function will produce this = undefined
      d3.selectAll('.edgelabel').style('fill', '#999');
      d3.select(this).style('fill', 'blue');
    });

    const node = zoomContainer
      .selectAll('.node')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .call(
        d3
          .drag()
          .on('start', (d) => this.dragended(d3, d, simulation))
          .on('drag', function dragged(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x;
            d.fy = d3.event.y;
          })
          .on('end', (d) => this.dragended(d3, d, simulation))
      );

    node
      .append('circle')
      .style('fill', '#fff')
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .style('fill-opacity', '1')
      .style('stroke-opacity', '0.5')
      .attr('id', (d, i) => d.id)
      .attr('r', 28);
    svg.selectAll('circle').on('click', function () {
      // arrow function will produce this = undefined
      d3.selectAll('.nodeText').style('fill', 'black');
      d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll('.nodeText').style('fill', 'blue');
    });

    node
      .append('image')
      .attr('xlink:href', 'https://github.com/favicon.ico')
      .attr('x', -10)
      .attr('y', -40)
      .attr('width', 16)
      .attr('class', 'image')
      .attr('height', 16);
    node
      .append('svg:foreignObject')
      .attr('class', 'delete-icon')
      .html('<div style="color:green;padding-left: 50px;">remove</div>')
      .text('delete');

    const nodeText = node
      .data(nodes)
      .append('text')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .attr('dy', -3)
      .attr('y', -25)
      .attr('class', 'nodeText')
      .attr('id', 'nodeText');

    nodeText
      .selectAll('tspan')
      .data((d, i) => d.label)
      .enter()
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('class', 'nodeTextTspan')
      .text((d) => d)
      .style('font-size', '12px')
      .attr('x', -10)
      .attr('dx', 10)
      .attr('dy', 22);
    svg.selectAll('.nodeText').on('click', function () {
      d3.selectAll('.nodeText').style('fill', 'black');
      d3.select(this).style('fill', 'blue');
    });

    node.append('title').text(function (d) {
      return d.id;
    });

    simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', () => {
      this.ticked(link, node, edgepaths, edgelabels);
    });

    simulation.force('link').links(links);
  }

  public update(data, element) {
    const svg = d3.select(element);
    return this._update(d3, svg, data);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
IE11 does not like `<tspans>` inside of `<textPaths>` therefore:

I've implemented some of @herrstrietzel solution into my [new demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-czqwvh?file=src/app/directed-graph-experiment.service.ts). The `<tspans>` are now directly inside of the `<text>` elements and each `<text>` has a dynamic x/y coordinates to lay it on the `<path>` as we no longer have `<textPaths>` to do this for us. I've had to do a lot of the rework inside of the `ticked()` method to gain access to the latest x/y coords as you do not get these outside. One issue remains:

```
// gets the coordinates of the edgepaths to use for the <text> positioning
edgepaths.each(function (d) {
  source_x = d.source.x;
  source_y = d.source.y;
  target_x = d.target.x;
  target_y = d.target.y;
});

let p1 = { x: source_x, y: source_y };
let p2 = { x: target_x, y: target_y };

// centers the <text> on the path
let textAnchor = this.interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, 0.5);

// Adds the x/y attribute to the <text> elements
edgelabels.attr('x', textAnchor.x).attr('y', textAnchor.y)
```

The text elements share the same coordinates and therefore share the same path... not sure why it hasn't adjusted inside the loop. The index of the first label that's already there should get the first index coordinate, but for some reason they are all just getting one set of path coordinates. p1 and p2 always give me the last coordinates in the array of edges.

Comment: I think a way to add text to a path without using <textPath> may firm thigs up a little. Somehow using the transform on the <text> element for position of the path.

Comment: Its a big file. That const is the complete part that creates the tspans. If you open in another browser you will have access to the code... the tricky part is the testing to see if its worked(as you said nothing opens in ie11)

Comment: I'm currently trying to get the x/y coords and add them to the tspans in the ticked() method. Something like that to bypass using <textPath>. Then I will need to find the middle of those two coords.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. Here is the rendered SVG that works - IE11 doesn't like tspan's inside textPaths, so you have to separate each label into its own text + textPath element with an appropriate dy attribute on the text element.

```html
<svg _ngcontent-c1="" height="600" width="900" style="cursor: move;"><g _ngcontent-c1="" ng-reflect-zoomable-of="[object SVGSVGElement]">
  <line class="link" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" style="stroke: rgb(153, 153, 153); stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-width: 2px;" x1="609.1621195478509" y1="362.0472615717732" x2="120.80347004842467" y2="254.41514023225977">
    <title>label one,label two,label three</title></line>
  
  <line class="link" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" style="stroke: rgb(153, 153, 153); stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-width: 2px;" x1="620.0342472996117" y1="283.53757565928413" x2="120.80347004842467" y2="254.41514023225977">
    
    <title>really Long Link text,tom</title>
      
    </line>
  
  <path class="edgepath" fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="0" id="edgepath0" d="M 609.1621195478509 362.0472615717732 L 120.80347004842467 254.41514023225977"></path><path class="edgepath" fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="0" id="edgepath1" d="M 620.0342472996117 283.53757565928413 L 120.80347004842467 254.41514023225977"></path>
  
 <text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel0" font-size="10" style="text-anchor: middle;" transform="rotate(180 370.5402526855469 287.623779296875)" dy="0">
  <textPath xlink:href="#edgepath0" dominant-baseline="middle" startOffset="50%" style="cursor: pointer;">
label one
    </textPath>
  </text>
  
   <text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel0" font-size="10" style="text-anchor: middle;" transform="rotate(180 370.5402526855469 287.623779296875)" dy="22">
    <textPath xlink:href="#edgepath0" dominant-baseline="middle" startOffset="50%" style="cursor: pointer;">
    label two
    </textPath>
    </text>
  
  <text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel0" font-size="10" style="text-anchor: middle;" transform="rotate(180 370.5402526855469 287.623779296875)" dy="44">
    <textPath xlink:href="#edgepath0" dominant-baseline="middle" startOffset="50%" style="cursor: pointer;">
    label three
    </textPath>
    </text>
  
<text class="edgelabel" id="edgelabel1" font-size="10" style="text-anchor: middle;" transform="rotate(180 370.2359619140625 260.2969512939453)"><textPath xlink:href="#edgepath1" dominant-baseline="middle" startOffset="50%" style="cursor: pointer;"><tspan class="edgelabels" dx="0">really Long Link text</tspan><tspan class="edgelabels" x="0" dy="22" dx="0">tom</tspan></textPath></text><g class="node" transform="translate(609.1621195478509, 362.0472615717732)"><circle id="5678" r="28" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: pointer; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 0.5;"></circle><image xlink:href="https://github.com/favicon.ico" x="-10" y="-40" width="16" class="image" height="16"></image><foreignObject class="delete-icon">delete</foreignObject><text dy="-3" y="-25" class="nodeText" id="nodeText" style="text-anchor: middle; cursor: pointer;"><tspan class="nodeTextTspan" x="-10" dx="10" dy="22" style="font-size: 12px;">Red</tspan><tspan class="nodeTextTspan" x="-10" dx="10" dy="22" style="font-size: 12px;">BMW</tspan><tspan class="nodeTextTspan" x="-10" dx="10" dy="22" style="font-size: 12px;">Fast</tspan></text><title>5678</title></g><g class="node" transform="translate(120.80347004842467, 254.41514023225977)"><circle id="2494EA62" r="28" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: pointer; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 0.5;"></circle><image xlink:href="https://github.com/favicon.ico" x="-10" y="-40" width="16" class="image" height="16"></image><foreignObject class="delete-icon">delete</foreignObject><text dy="-3" y="-25" class="nodeText" id="nodeText" style="text-anchor: middle; cursor: pointer;"><tspan class="nodeTextTspan" x="-10" dx="10" dy="22" style="font-size: 12px;">Cool</tspan><tspan class="nodeTextTspan" x="-10" dx="10" dy="22" style="font-size: 12px;">Brown</tspan><tspan class="nodeTextTspan" x="-10" dx="10" dy="22" style="font-size: 12px;">Ford Cortina</tspan></text><title>2494EA62</title></g><g class="node" transform="translate(620.0342472996117, 283.53757565928413)"><circle id="123" r="28" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: pointer; fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 0.5;"></circle><image xlink:href="https://github.com/favicon.ico" x="-10" y="-40" width="16" class="image" height="16"></image><foreignObject class="delete-icon">delete</foreignObject><text dy="-3" y="-25" class="nodeText" id="nodeText" style="text-anchor: middle; cursor: pointer;"><tspan class="nodeTextTspan" x="-10" dx="10" dy="22" style="font-size: 12px;">Aston</tspan><tspan class="nodeTextTspan" x="-10" dx="10" dy="22" style="font-size: 12px;">Martin</tspan></text><title>123</title></g></g><defs><marker id="arrowhead" viewBox="-0 -5 10 10" refX="27" refY="0" orient="auto" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="8" xoverflow="visible"><path d="M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5" fill="#999" style="stroke: none;"></path></marker></defs></svg>
```

Comment: Ok I did think of this, but then thought against it as the ids for the textPaths would be duplicated and I read somewhere this would cause an issue. I will have to look at refiguring my code to implement the above unless you can beat me to it ;)

Comment: Well you should probably have unique ID's for the text elements - but I think the textPath's should be fine?

Answer (score 1):

Not a proper `d3.js` solution, but should be able to adapt/include it in your script.

#### Calculate centered text x/y coordinates and rotation angles according to line/graph

We're using `<text>` elements placed at the middle of the line/graph replacing `<textpath>` usage.

##### Get centered text anchor coordinates replacing `startOffset="50%"`

Since you know the line's starting and end points, we can easily interpolate a mid point like so:

```
let p1 = {x:x1, y:y1};
let p2 = {x:x2, y:y2};

let textAnchor = {x:(p1.x+p2.x)/2, y:(p1.y+p2.y)/2};
```

The textAnchor point coordinates will become the `<text>` elements new `x` and `y` atribute values.

##### Get rotation angle

```
 let angle = (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180) / Math.PI;
```

This variable is used so set the transform rotate property according to the line's drawing angle.

```js
// example coordinates - should come from your data object
let x1 = line1.x1.baseVal.value;
let x2 = line1.x2.baseVal.value;
let y1 = line1.y1.baseVal.value;
let y2 = line1.y2.baseVal.value;


let p1 = {x:x1, y:y1};
let p2 = {x:x2, y:y2};


/**
* calculte mid point on line
* use LERP helper if you need to place the mid point at other positions: 
* e.g t=0.75 = 75%
*/
let textAnchor = interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, 0.5);
// use this for simple centered alignment
//let textAnchor = {x:(p1.x+p2.x)/2, y:(p1.y+p2.y)/2};


// move parent <text> element to mid point
textLabel.setAttribute('x', textAnchor.x)
textLabel.setAttribute('y', textAnchor.y);

// add x and dy attributes to tspan for pdeudo-multiline appearance
let lineHeight = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(textLabel).fontSize)*1.2;
setTspanMultiline(textLabel, lineHeight)

// rotate according to line center point
let angle = getAngle(p1, p2);
// svg attribute transform
textLabel.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${angle} ${textAnchor.x} ${textAnchor.y})`)

// css style equivalent
//textLabel.style.transform = `translate(${textAnchor.x}px, ${textAnchor.y}px) rotate(${angle}deg) translate(-${textAnchor.x}px, -${textAnchor.y}px)`;


function setTspanMultiline(textEl, dy){
  let tspans = textEl.querySelectorAll('tspan');
  let totalDy = (tspans.length-1)*dy;
  let x= +textEl.getAttribute('x');
  tspans.forEach((tspan, i)=>{
    tspan.setAttribute('x', x);
    if(i>0){
        tspan.setAttribute('dy', dy);
    }
  })
  textEl.setAttribute('dy', totalDy/-2 )
}

/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, t = 0.5) {
  //t: 0.5 - point in the middle
  if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
    p1.x = p1[0];
    p1.y = p1[1];
  }
  if (Array.isArray(p2)) {
    p2.x = p2[0];
    p2.y = p2[1];
  }
  let [x, y] = [(p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x, (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y];
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}

// get angle helper
function getAngle(p1, p2) {
  let angle = (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180) / Math.PI;
  return angle;
}
```

```css
svg{
  width:50em;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  overflow:visible;
}

text{
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 500 100">
  <line id="line1" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="25%" y2="75%" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" />
  <text x="0" id="textLabel" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
    <tspan class="edgelabels">line one</tspan>
    <tspan class="edgelabels">line two long</tspan>
    <tspan class="edgelabels">line three</tspan>
    <tspan class="edgelabels">line four</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

In the above example I'm using the `setTspanMultiline(textEl, dy)` helper function to generate the correct `x`, `y` and `dy` values.

```
<text x="250" id="textLabel" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" y="50" dy="-18" transform="rotate(5.710593137499643 250 50)">
    <tspan class="edgelabels" x="250">line one</tspan>
    <tspan class="edgelabels" x="250" dy="12">line two long</tspan>
    <tspan class="edgelabels" x="250" dy="12">line three</tspan>
    <tspan class="edgelabels" x="250" dy="12">line four</tspan>
  </text>
```

Basically all `<tspan>` inherit the `x` value from the parent `<text>` elements.
The relative `dy` will emulate the line height.
The parent `<text>` `dy` value will vertically center the text around the line and is calculated like so:

(Total number of tspans - 1) * dy

```
  let tspans = textEl.querySelectorAll('tspan');
  let totalDy = (tspans.length-1)*dy;
```

Comment: This looks good. Not convinced that the coords come from my data object until ticked() has been triggered. I will have to see if I can get thisbinto my stackblitz example

Comment: So I am nearly there with this... https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-bu6kbr?file=src/app/directed-graph-experiment.service.ts  - there was some bits I couldnt add to my example, I'm still creating the tspans in the d3 way. Two issues outstanding as per the demo... the text no longer rotates "up-right" when 180 degrees is reached and the <text> all have the same link coordinates therefore are all on the same line.

Comment: You mean something like this?  [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dzry6q-xtzuwa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirected-graph-experiment.service.ts) - just added a condition to the `getAngle()`  helper:   
`getAngle(p1, p2) {
  let angle = (Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180) / Math.PI;
    if(angle>90 || angle<-90 ){
      angle +=180
    }
    return angle;
  }`

Comment: Great thanks! Nearly there with this.

Comment: I think I need to match up the index in the ticked()function with the index that created the <text> elements

Comment: I see - you'll need to calculate `dy` offsets according to the current index in an extra loop (no idea how to do this in d3). Maybe appending all tspans into one `<text>`element is more convenient. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/Expeyym)